# What is the difference between ffmpeg -r output option and framerate filter?

Tags: ffmpeg

I want to reencode a 60 fps video with 30 fps, to be played in a less capable hardware.
What is the difference between using the `-r 30` output option, the `framerate=fps=30` filter, or simply the `framestep=step=2` filter?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/51143100

Comment: So, there is a third filter for doing what I want: `fps=fps=30`. It makes more sense to drop the frames in the filterchain, so that further filters are applied only to the frames that will go to the output file. Since I can see no difference in their result, I will use `framestep`. Please point out if I am missing something important.

Comment: If your video is variable frame-rate, framestep may leave larger (or smaller) intervals between frames than intended.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of that, but I think I can be sure it has constant framerate, ffprobe says avg_frame_rate = 60000/1001.